# c# usersettings exception 'could not find a part of the path' during save

Tags: c#, exception, settings

I'm working for the first time with the built-in usersettings for a winforms appllication in c#.
During the work I am confronted with the following problem.

In my development environment, everything works as expected, but as soon as I try to change the default settings on another machine, the following exception is thrown:

> System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: Failed to save settings: An error occurred loading a configuration file: Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Microsoft\App.exe_Url_ouhyykeidfbgy4o2rhziaurj2zdqs5x4\1.0.0.0\tpqztu3w.tmp'. (C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Microsoft\App.exe_Url_ouhyykeidfbgy4o2rhziaurj2zdqs5x4\1.0.0.0\user.config) ---> System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: An error occurred loading a configuration file: Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Microsoft\App.exe_Url_ouhyykeidfbgy4o2rhziaurj2zdqs5x4\1.0.0.0\tpqztu3w.tmp'. (C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Microsoft\App.exe_Url_ouhyykeidfbgy4o2rhziaurj2zdqs5x4\1.0.0.0\user.config) ---> System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Microsoft\App.exe_Url_ouhyykeidfbgy4o2rhziaurj2zdqs5x4\1.0.0.0\tpqztu3w.tmp'.

I try to save the Settings as follows:

```
Settings.Default.TheSettingsKey = Value;
Settings.Default.Save();
```

Is it required to have some special rights to be able to save user settings?
Or am I missing something else?

Thanks for your help.

**EDIT**
I've just found out, that the folder where the user settings should be stored is not existing (C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Microsoft\App.exe_Url_ouhyykeidfbgy4o2rhziaurj2zdqs5x4\1.0.0.0). For my understanding it should be created when the settings are changed. Do I have to, or can I, force the creation of this folder?

Answer (score 0):

```
Properties.Settings.Default["SomeProperty"] = "Some Value";
Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```